# How can I stop Joyride explicitly?

Tags: javascript, zurb-joyride

I can start Joyride using `$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');` code without refreshing the page. However, is there any method except using the `class="joyride-close-tip"` to stop the joyride?

Comment: Care to explain why choose to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer myself. Might be useful to others as well.

```
$(document).foundation('joyride', 'hide');
```

It hides the joyride.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).foundation('joyride', 'off')

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.